# Completely reusable, stainless-steel, zero-waste Nespresso pods any good?

Tags: espresso-machine, nespresso, pods

Getting ready to buy an inexpensive espresso setup for at work. I've been very happy with the EC155, but I've noticed that Nespresso machines are very well engineered, very inexpensive, and much smaller.

I will not use anything that has throwaway parts, and compostability claims are bogus, but I did find these (actually) zero-waste refillable pods:

- [here](https://coffee-cave.com/products/nespresso-stainless-steel-refillable-reusable-capsule-zero-waste-life-long-use)
- [here](https://www.compatible-capsules.com/)
- [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MZWHAKK)

Does anyone have experience or educated hypotheses about how well these would work?

Comment: They will be as good as the disposable Nespresso capsules, depending on which coffee you fill it with, how it is ground etc.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I was looking for zero waste pods and you’ve linked three!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually i made quite a good experience with some of these reusable capsules even tho they are quite expensive. Nevertheless you save in the long-term and also save a lot of waste(had quite a lot of empty plastic capsules in the past). Meanwhile there are some refillable capsules on the market which provide at the same quality a way lower price. These ones for instance https://bit.ly/34Z1MH4

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR:
Depends if the coffee style matches the pod design.

How a Nespresso machine works:

1. pod put in the machine gets pierced on the upper side
2. hot water is released into the pod
3. pressure rises inside the pod
4. due to high pressure a membrane burst at the bottom of the pod
5. brewed coffee is released

By modifying the membrane to burst at a higher or lower pressure, other flavors will be extracted from the coffee, like pour over and espresso.